# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot determine loading status from unexpected alert open

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, alert

On the login page that I am trying to automate, generates a pop-up for invalid login credentials. I am using a try, catch block to switch control to alert message and check whether the alert pops or not in order to decide between successful and unsuccessful login. Below is the function I am using for this purpose:

```
public alertChecker isAlertPresent(WebDriver driver)
    {
        alertChecker acObj = new alertChecker();
        try{            
            Alert alt = driver.switchTo().alert();
            acObj.sAlertMessage = alt.getText(); // get content of the Alter Message
            acObj.bAlertPresent = true;
            alt.accept();           
        }    
        catch (NoAlertPresentException Ex)
        {           
            acObj.bAlertPresent = false;
            acObj.sAlertMessage = "";
        }
        return acObj;
    }
```

I have 4 inputs, 1st has valid credentials and remaining are invalid. I am able to run the test for one valid followed by another 2 invalid combinations. While running the test for last set of credentials, I am getting below error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
>   unknown error: cannot determine loading status from unexpected alert
>   open

I am using Chrome browser. Please help me resolve this

Comment: which version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: The issue is with the latest version of chromedriver.exe. I downgraded to version 2.18 and it was resolved

Answer (score 3):

This isn't an answer, but it's too big for a comment. This is a bug in the latest chrome. I would suggest starring and commenting here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1362&can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Status%20Pri%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=

Comment: Thanks! The last comment, there, says this has been fixed as of version "2.23". Simply replacing the executable solved this problem for me https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Comment: I saw it was in 2.21 and fixed by 2.24